# Is it possible to load an unmanaged dll asynchronously?

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged, chromium-embedded, cefglue

I am working on a word vsto add-in that have integrated cefglue (a .net binding for cef) as its webview control. But when loading libcef.dll, it will block the startup of word until finished the loading.

I have tried load this unmanaged dll libcef.dll in a new thread but it still block the main thread. Is it possible to load an unmanaged dll asynchronously in a new thread?

Comment: I think you are looking for the `async` keywords. I personally have very little knowledge of them so I can't really make a complete answer for this. I have found this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2012/01/23/using-async-for-file-access/) though.

Comment: @Tyler thanks. After some try, I think the idea is ok but it still block the startup of word, which is maybe relate to the way loading unmanaged dll in word.